# How to limit a query in discrete chunks? MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to limit a query in discrete groups? For example, let's say I have this query below.

```
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
|    1 |    A |
|    1 |    B |
|    2 |    C |
|    2 |    D |
|    3 |    E |
|    3 |    F |
```

I want the limit on this query to be 5 rows. However, I only want it to show discrete complete groups based on the first column. So that means I don't want to show (3, E) since (3, F) would be cut off. So it would only show the first 4 rows.

Is there a way to write this dynamic logic into a MySQL query?

Comment: Groups are based on `col1` value only ?

Comment: 1st : the data you provide is not query, that is dataset or expected result. 2nd - It is unclear what you are asking. 3rd - RTFM quick response is : `SELECT * from myTable LIMIT 5`

Comment: @Alex Yes, sorry, I should have put an example query as SELECT * from myTable LIMIT 5;

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes, the groups are based on col1 value only.

Comment: @Sebastian What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: The answer provided by Thorsten Kettner below worked! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count rows in a subquery:

```
select col1, col2
from mytable m1
where (select count(*) from mytable m2 where m2.col1 <= m1.col1) <= 5
order by col1, col2;
```

Comment: How did you figure this out by the way? I'm just curious and would want to figure this query out and if I could read about it somewhere.

Comment: I think this is rather easy; you look at a row, take its `col1` and ask: if I take all rows with this `col1` and lower, would that still be within the given limit? There is nothing special about this query, really. It happens every now and then that we read from the same table twice and use different table aliases in order to tell the two rows we are looking at apart. Subqueries in the `SELECT`, `FROM` or `WHERE` clause are also common. Here it's about criteria on whether to show a row or not, so it's a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Sebastian To be more specific, it is a Correlated Subquery. Refer the docs for some understanding and examples: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html